# JFrame wont show in netbeans platform

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, netbeans-platform

I have application build on netbeans project extension. I need to show new separated Jframe on button click in TopComponet. But when I call frame.setVisible(true) nothing happens. I tried method pack() and it doesn't help.

```
public void onClick(){
   MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I already read a few people had same problem but I haven't found any solution.

MyFrame Class

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public MyFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}            
}
```

EDIT:

```
javax.swing.JFrame t = new javax.swing.JFrame("test");
t.pack();
t.setVisible(true);
//works

MyFrame t = new MyFrame();
t.pack();
t.setVisible(true);
//doesnt work
```

UserDetailWindowFrame is JFrame genereted by Netbeans.

Comment: how are you calling the onClick() method?

Comment: button.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){....

Comment: okay problem with this is, MyFrame is the name of your gui created class for your application, if you simply create a new instance of your class if you close one it will exit the application.  Why do you need the 2nd frame?

Comment: MyJFrame is not main JFrame of the application. Aplication is netbeans platform extension. I need to show some content after button click in non-modal window which is always on top.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we were facing some problems with JFrame and TopComponent coupled together in one of our projects. 
I am trying to suggest one of the approaches. It might be somehow helpful. When your start a Netbeans Platform application, it creates a default Topcomponent, provided you don´t have any Topcomponent of your own. We wanted to ignore the default Top Component all together, and provide our own JFrame.

When the application was starting, we provided the following argument inside a config file(our one is a netbeans maven Project)-

```
default_options="-J-Dorg.netbeans.core.WindowSystem.show=false"
```

When the module is loaded we started our customized JFrame within the following chunk of code-

```
WindowManager.getDefault().invokeWhenUIReady(new Runnable(){    
@Override
public void run(){
MainJFrame parentJFrame = new MainJFrame("");
parentJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
parentJFrame.add(myJPanel);// your JPanel will come here
parentJFrame .revalidate();
parentJFrame .repaint();
parentJFrame .setVisible(true);
 }
 });
```

If you are always working within the same TopComponent, then you might want to close/hide the TopComponent before showing your own JFrame.The following code might help-

```
 WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().setVisible(false);
                            or
 WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().setEnabled(false);
```

Hopefully, this helps. Using JFrame inside a Netbeans Platform Applicaiton can be nasty sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work creating a new empty frame.

```
public void onClick()
{
    MyFrame newframe = new MyFrame();
    newframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(1); //adding this will allow the new frames to close without the application closing
    newframe.setVisible(true);
    newframe.pack();
}
```

however if you close it, it will exit the application, you may want to think about building a specific new frame.

Comment: I don't understand what do you try to say.

Comment: One sec you are using the Java gui builder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set size on the JFrame and position it to the center(**frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)**) and see if it works. Here is the related code:

```
private void initComponents() {    
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);

setSize(1000, 1000);
//pack(); no need to call this as we set a fixed size
```

}

Call your onClick method like this:

```
 private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       onClick();

    }
```

Here is the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(){
   MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
   //frame.pack(); no need to call this as we set a fixed size
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // position it to the center
   frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: could you share a bit of your code for UserDetailWindowFrame ?

Comment: I did. Its just autogenerated JFrame by netbeans

Comment: I edited class and no JFrame is showed anyway. Class is edited in question

Comment: Okay, perhaps if you set size it will show. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method .show() after creating an object of Class MyFrame, so it should seem more like this:

```
public void onClick(){
    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    frame.pack();
    frame.show(); //it may create the frame at the top left corner.
}
```